# Jsonwebtoken verification causing NGINX timeout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, jwt, passport.js

The general tech stack for the application I'm working on is NodeJS backend, React frontend, NGINX for a reverse proxy to link the two. All containerized using docker compose.

The issue I seem to be running into is that when I try and verify JWTwhich are stored in an HTTP-only cookie, passed to the backend on API requests, it's being held up on verification causing a timeout. Specifically this error:

`6#6: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "POST /api/api/v1/getUserInfo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.27.0.2:8080/api/v1/getUserInfo", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/account"`

I've tried upping the proxy_read_timeout/proxy_send_timeout in nginx but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Here's my JWT signing function:

```js
var privateKEY = 'testkey';
const issuer: String = 'test123';
const audience: String = 'test123';

module.exports = {
    sign: (payload: any) => {
        // Token signing options
        var signOptions = {
            issuer:     issuer,
            audience: audience,
            expiresIn:  "12h", // 12 hour validity
        };
        return jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions);
    }
}
```

How I'm calling that function:

```js
const token = jwt.sign({
                            id: user._id,
                            firstName: user.firstName,
                            role: user.role
                        });
```

How I'm getting the token from the cookie:

```js
var cookieExtractor = function(req: Request) {
    var token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies) {
        token = req.cookies["token"];
    }

    return token;
};

const issuer: string = "test123";
const audience: string = "test123";

var opts = {
    secretOrKey: 'testkey',
    issuer: issuer,
    audience: audience,
    jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor
};
```

My Passport-JWT strategy:

```js
    passport.use(
        "jwt",
        new JWTStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
            UserModel.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.id }, (err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err, false);
                }

                if (user) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });
        })
    );
```

How I'm calling the authentication:

```js
    app.post(`${versioning}/updateUserInfo`, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
            *insert code here*
        });
    });
```

When I've traced through the code, it seems to pause at a jwt.verify call in the passport-jwt library and then never gets past that. I'm new to JWT and all that so maybe I'm doing something wrong along the way, I just can't figure out why this all of a sudden stopped working (this is a side project and the last time I worked on it ~1 week ago, this problem never occurred).

**EDIT**

For those experiencing this as well, I never found a clear reason as to why. I updated my jsonwebtoken library and stopped using Passport for my JWT verification and it started working for me. This is now my JWT verification method which I use instead of using the Passport method.

```
verifyTokenOnly: (token: any, cb: any) => {
    jwt.verify(
        token,
        publicUserKey,
        { audience: audience, algorithms: ["RS256"] },
        (err: any, jwt_payload: any) => {
            if (err || !jwt_payload) {
                cb(err, null);
            } else {
                UserModel.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.sub }, (err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        cb(err, null);
                    }

                    if (user) {
                        cb(null, user);
                    } else {
                        cb(null, false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
},
```

Aside from doing that I didn't really change anything and it started working and hasn't happened since.

Comment: Hey there. Do you have additional info you can share? Maybe you found something else until now :-? I am experiencing the same issue and cannot link it to any particularity

Comment: @AndreiTerecoasa Unfortunately I was never able to really pin it down. I edited my original post with what I changed and I haven't faced any issues since though.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. I switched to using `jwt-simple` from https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple and everything worked.

My guess is that `jsonwebtoken` is doing fancier things (e.g., supporting both sync and async calls) and this fancy stuff does not work well with njs.

You may find the https://github.com/aocks/ox_jwt useful. It's an open source and relatively minimal and stand alone implementation of JWT authentication via nginx using javascript. The JWT decoding and verification code is documented and short so you can add your own logging to see if you have problems.